# Target without some of the classes of the scenes in the Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, uistoryboard

I have a number of targets in my project, each using the same Storyboard but with just a selection of the classes linked in it. Usually Xcode does not complain, at least it does not on the iPhone version, nor in most targets. Yet a specific one complaints about two specific classes with:

> Unknown class ****** in Interface Builder file.
>
> Unknown class $$$$$$ in Interface Builder file.

notwithstanding there are many other scenes in the storyboard the class of which is not included in the target, even in this specific case.

It happens just when I execute the app on the iPad (simulator) and after a while it crashes on the UIApplicationMain; I do not know if the two things are connected, though.

Is there some way in which Xcode decides to check some scenes of the storyboard and some other not for the existence of the corresponding class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Swift is module based. Each target is a module. A class is defined in a specific module, and is namespaced to that module.

Thus, ViewController in MyFirstTarget is different from ViewController in MySecondTarget - they are `MyFirstTarget.ViewController` and `MySecondTarget.ViewController`.

If you look in the storyboard's Identity inspector, you will see that in fact it tells you what module it thinks this class belongs to. Thus it can become fatally confused if that module isn't present when the nib loads.

Answer (score 0):

More simply I had introduced a SplitView in the other targets not been used in the one in object, and when it tried to display it as entrance scene it crashed. As a matter of fact the unknown classes were the one in the master controller possibly been displayed along with the split view.

I fixed the issue by duplicating the iPad Storyboard to have one with the Splitview and another without it.